# Wrapping a .addEventListener in a div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I am compleatly new to js and I need help using html inbetween the lines.

i have this event:

```
 eventSource.addEventListener('Uptime', function(e) {
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(e.data);
        var tempSpan = document.getElementById("uptime");
        var tsSpan   = document.getElementById("tstamp");
        tempSpan.innerHTML = parsedData.data;
        tempSpan.style.fontSize = "28px";
        tsSpan.innerHTML = "At timestamp " + parsedData.published_at;
        tsSpan.style.fontSize = "9px";
    }, false);
```

it listens for events from my Spark Core en updates my website with the status.

What i want is the status being showed inside my div.

```
<div id="on"> </div>
```

Is this possible?

Complete code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Spark.aspx.cs"     Inherits="Spark" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
     <span id="uptime"></span><br>
    <span id="tstamp"></span>

   <br><br>
<button onclick="start()">Connect</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function start() {


    document.getElementById("uptime").innerHTML = "Waiting for data...";
    var deviceID = "";
    var accessToken = "";
    var eventSource = new EventSource("https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/" + deviceID + "/events/?access_token=" + accessToken);

    eventSource.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
        console.log("Opened!"); },false);

    eventSource.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
        console.log("Errored!"); },false);

    <!--THIS IS THE METHOD I WANT INSIDE THE DIV-->
    eventSource.addEventListener('Uptime', function(e) {
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(e.data);
        var tempSpan = document.getElementById("uptime");
        var tsSpan   = document.getElementById("tstamp");
        tempSpan.innerHTML = parsedData.data;
        tempSpan.style.fontSize = "28px";
        tsSpan.innerHTML = "At timestamp " + parsedData.published_at;
        tsSpan.style.fontSize = "9px";
        var div = document.createElement("div")
        div.innerHTML = parsedData.status;

        document.body.appendChild(div);

        document.getElementById("on").innerHTML = parsedData.status;
    }, false);

}
</script>
```

Heres a screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivp8X.jpg

To be more spesific, I'm trying to show the text "Borte" in the div

Answer (score 2):

At the end of your event, just do (assuming `status` is a value inside `parsedData`):

```
document.getElementById("on").innerHTML = parsedData.status;
```

That's assuming you have the `div` on the page, if you don't then you'd have to create it first:

```
var div = document.createElement("div")
div.innerHTML = parsedData.status;

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: This did not work for me. cant see the div appearing on the site

Comment: @user2927356 Are you sure? Have you looked in dev tools to see if the div is present, but just not immediately visible? If it isn't there, post your full HTML.

Comment: may be poster want to create a div and put the content and then append it to the dom.

Comment: @user2927356 Check my edit, I didn't realise you didn't have the `div` on the page already.

Comment: aha. I should put this outside of the addeventlistener() right?

Comment: @user2927356 You can have it all inside the event listener at the end of it.

Comment: Had some problems with the css. Now that that is fixed, This still dosent work. all that shows is "undefined". Posting the html code in the edit.

Comment: @user2927356 If you `alert(parsedData.status)` before appending the `div`, is there anything in it? What is your status field called and where does it come from?

Comment: Do you men write alert(parsedData.status) just before document.body.appendChild(div);? that wont work. The status is coming from c++ code in a Spark Core hooked up to a sensor

Comment: @user2927356 Okay, so what exactly do you want to display in that `div`? It has to be some fields that you're returning from the server. I see you use `published_at` in that method, which field contains the status?